# How can I align content at the bottom of the div?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have been trying to align my menu div at the bottom of the my logo div in the same line as of my logo inside my header.

```
  <div id="header">
            <div id="top-bar">
            </div>
            <div id="clear"></div>
            <div id="logo">
                <img id="logoimg" src="images/KTMLogo.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Movies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Theaters</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
  #header {
   background-color:#e1874b;
   border-bottom-left-radius:25px;
   border-bottom-right-radius:25px;
   float:left;
   position:relative;
  } 

  #logo {
   width:280px;
  }

  #logo img {
   max-height:240px;
   max-width:240px;  
  }

  #menu { 
   font-size:18px;
   padding:20px;
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)100%);
   width:500px;
   margin-left:300px;
   }
```

I want my menu div to start from the bottom of my logo in the same line.

Comment: Where is the menu div displaying currently? I suppose it should be after your image which should be what you are asking for.

Comment: @Homer Kamal: should it be after the logo,or under it

Comment: What do you mean by "same line"?  Please clarify or be a little more specific.

Comment: It's displaying below the image with left margin.

Comment: @HomerKamal check my anwser then

Comment: @HomerKamal i have added two demos,i would like to see if it is what you expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
#menu ul li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

to place the menu items on one line.

to place then to the right of the image add.

```
#menu,#logo {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

and remove or correct the margin-left rule under menu selector.

Answer (score 0):

Menu under the logo

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/a24B6/)

```
#menu { 
   font-size:18px;
   padding:0px;
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)100%);
   width:500px;
   margin-left:0px;
   }
```

i think you need this

[`UPDATED DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/a24B6/1/)

```
#header {
   background-color:#e1874b;
   border-bottom-left-radius:25px;
   border-bottom-right-radius:25px;
   float:left;
   position:relative;
  } 

  #logo {
   width:280px;
  }

  #logo img {
   max-height:240px;
   max-width:240px;  
  }

  #menu { 
   font-size:18px;
   padding:0px;
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)100%);
   width:500px;
   margin-left:0px;
   }
#menu ul{

    display:inline-block;


}

#menu ul li{

      display:inline-block;

}
```

[**updated again**](http://jsfiddle.net/a24B6/3/)

Comment: i don't want it under my logo. I want to start it just after my logo at the bottom of the header.

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
#menu { 
  font-size:18px;
  padding:20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)100%);
  width:500px;
  margin-left:300px;
  float: left;
```

}
To have your menu on the same line with your image use `float: left;`

And to have the list in the same line use `display: inline-block;`

```
#menu ul li {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eJeQ7/)

```
 #logo {    
    float: left;
  }

#menu { 
   margin-left: 0px;
}
```